# ios: Compare NSString to "<null>" not working

Tags: ios, json, null, nsstring

I am consuming a web service that returns **JSON**. One of the values I get is `"< null >"`.

When I run the follwoing code the if statment still get executed when it is not suppposed to.

Any reason why?

```
NSDictionary *location = [dictionary valueForKey:@"geoLocation"];       //get the product name
NSString *latitude = [location valueForKey:@"latitude"];
NSLog(@"%@", latitude);

NSString *longitude = [location valueForKey:@"longitude"];

if (![latitude isEqual: @"<null>"] && ![longitude isEqual: @"<null>"]) {
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.longitude = [latitude doubleValue];
    coordinate.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
    [self buildMarketsList:coordinate title:title subtitle:nil]; //build the browse list product
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I am consuming a web service that returns JSON. One of the values I get is "< null >"

Aha. Two possibilities:

I. The JSON doesn't contain latitude and longitude information. In this case, the keys for them aren't present in the dictionary you're getting back, so you are in fact obtaining a `nil` (or `NULL`) pointer. As messaging `nil` returns zero, both conditions will fire (due to the negation applied). Try this instead:

```
if (latitude != nil && longitude != nil)
```

and **never rely on the description of an object.**

II. Probably the JSON contains `null` values, and the JSON parser you're using turns `null` into `[NSNull null]`, and in turn you're trying to compare a string against that `NSNull`. In this case, try this:

```
if (![latitude isEqual:[NSNull null]] && ![longitude isEqual:[NSNull null]])
```

Comment: @Anupdas Thank you. I don't know why somebody thought this is wrong.

Comment: @EliMiller That's the description of `[NSNull null]`. You should also read the documentation of `NSLog()` more attentively.

Answer (score 2):

I had same Problem, But solved as below,
Replace your if with following,

```
if (![latitude isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && ![longitude isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you get null in a JSON response, you'll need to check against `NSNull`.

In your case, you should do something like this:

```
if ( [location valueForKey:@"longitude"] == [NSNull null]) {
     // is null object
}
```

Comment: Please don't compare objects using `==`.

Comment: "To test for a null object value, you must therefore make a direct object comparison." - Straight from Apple's documentation. They do a direct object comparison using == before using isEqual.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html

Comment: @H2CO3 - I almost never compare objects using == except this case...unless Apple's documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([latitude isEqual:[NSNull null]])
{
 //do something
 latitude = @"";
}
else
{
 //do something else
 latitude = json value
}
```

This is what I will do. This is because I need to store the value even if  a null return.